# Enabling multiple inputs before console closes

Tags: c++

My program is a text adventure game. I want to make it so that the console lets the user enter more than one input before the "Press any key to close this window" text comes up, or rather to replace it with another key to manually close the window. How would I go about this? I'm very new as you can probably tell.

Here is my code:

````
#include <string>

int main()

//        WINSTON PIGEYE    -    COOL NAME

{
    using namespace std;

    std::string answer; //player's input


    std::cout << "You are in your room, playing with your favourite toy, Spartacus. He's just about to give his great speech when you hear a knock at the door.\n";
    std::cout << "A few seconds pass by. You know it isn't your Mum because she would have said something by now.\n\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, answer);

    if (answer == "answer door" || answer == "investigate door" || answer == "investigate" || answer == "Answer Door" || answer == "Answer door" || answer == "investigate"
        || answer == "Investigate door" || answer == "Investigate Door" || answer == "Check door" || answer == "Check Door" || answer == "check door" ||
        answer == "answer" || answer == "Answer" || answer == "open door" || answer == "Open door" || answer == "Open Door" || answer == "open" || answer == "Open" || answer == "open sesame")
    {
        std::cout << "\nYou approach the door. \n\nYou think you see the door move out of place ever so slightly, but you're not sure. You turn the handle on the door but it won't open";
    }

    else if (answer == "ignore" || answer == "Ignore" || answer == "ignore door" || answer == "Ignore door" || answer == "Ignore the door" || answer == "continue playing"
        || answer == "Continue playing" || answer == "Keep playing" || answer == "keep playing" || answer == "finish speech" || answer == "Finish speech" || answer == "Finish Spartacus' speech" || answer == "finish Spartacus' speech" || answer == "finish spartacus' speech"
        || answer == "finish spartacus speech" || answer == "finish Spartacus speech" || answer == "Finish Spartacus speeech")
    {
        std::cout << "\nYou ignore the knocking on the door and Spartacus continues his speech. \n \nFrom this moment forth, we shall no longer live like rats, but as people, as human beings! We will finally know what it means to be truly free!\n\nThe imaginary crowd cheers and Spartacus is hailed a hero.\n";
        std::cout << "\n\n The End.\n\n";

    }

    else if (answer == "ask who's there" || answer == "ask\"who's there?\"" || answer == "Ask who's there?" || answer == "ask who's there?" || answer == "who's there?" || answer == "who's there" || answer == "Who's there?" || answer == "Hello?" || answer == "Hello"
        || answer == "hello" || answer == "\"Who's there?\"" || answer == "Who is it?" || answer == "who is it?" || answer ==
        "Mum?" || answer == "Mom?" || answer == "Mummy?" || answer == "Mommy?" || answer == "mum?" || answer == "mom?" || answer == "mummy?" || answer == "mommy?" || answer == "hello?")
    {

        std::cout << "\n\nThere is no answer.";
    }

    else
    {

        std::cout << "unrecognized command";
    }

}```
````

Comment: *... that the console lets the user enter more than one input before the ...* - please explain what do you mean by *more than once input*?

Comment: I use a copy of an old floppy disc that was hopelessly scrambled way back in the early nineties for cool names. The disk is so corrupt with age that I have a nigh-limitless source of names for D&D games, such as cHrio|ath.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that I wanted the user to be able to enter as many inputs as they like and not have the console close. So you can use different answers every time but not loop the text at the beginning.

Comment: @user4581301 haha, nice. I come up with a bunch of cool names all the time. I'm glad I wrote this one down because I probably would have forgotten it otherwise.

Comment: @RohanBari it was almost what I wanted but I just didn't want the first introductory text to appear again.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it so that the console lets the user enter more than one input before ...

Probably you meant by looping the code time and again, you may try this code template:

```
while (true) {
    // the code
    // some code...

    if (/* some condition */) {
        break; // to quit from the loop
    }
}
```

It'll loop (repeat) until the `break` statement occurs, and that'll only occur when the `while()` enters to the `if` condition coded in it.

Comment: Wait, I don't want to loop the text. I just want it so that the user can enter as many inputs as they like. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: @ShanePatrickO'sullivanBobey yes, the loop will execute infinitely as long as the user wants. You may use break statement as shown in the code to break from the loop.

Comment: If you think I still didn't understand, then sorry. You need to explain a bit clearly what you want if you don't want to loop it and use break statements to quit from the loop in certain conditions of `if`.

Comment: So for example, this is what it might look like:

"You are in your room, playing with your favourite toy, Spartacus. He's just about to give his great speech when you hear a knock at the door."

who's there?

There is no answer.

open door

You approach the door. 

You think you see the door move out of place ever so slightly, but you're not sure. You turn the handle on the door but it won't open.

So you would be able to enter multiple inputs but the first text doesn't reappear again. Does that make sense?